# Getting values of input fields, and do some calcutation with them

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

So I would like 3 input fields that they can write, inventories, av time and hours, I have seen a few answers that relate to this but I'm still unsure as i'm new to this. I have no knowledge of jquery so that's not an option, thanks.

```
<h3>Work out how much you could be saving!<h3>

<button type="button" class="calculate">Calculate</button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    // Do the Javscript here!

    function calc (inventories, hours, wage) {
        return (inventories * hours) * wage;
    }
    $('.calculate').click(function(){

        // Put variables here
        console.log (calc ( , , ));
        // Call the caclulation function

        // Output function to text here..

    });

</script>
```

Comment: What research have you attempted yourself? A search for "html javascript form" got me this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_input_examples.asp

Worth a look, I think. You might find other helpful links.

Comment: In your question you say that you do not know jquery so that is not an option, but you have jquery in your code example. Are you currently using jquery or not?

Answer (score 0):

Add inputs,

```
<input type="number" id="inventories" />
```

same for others

get the content of those fields by:

```
$("#inventories").val();
```

your calculate function would be something like:

```
var inventories = $("#inventories").val();
var wage = $("#wage").val();
var hours = $("#hours").val();
calc(inventories,hours,wage);
```